# Canvas: clearRect() does not clear drawImage()

Tags: javascript, canvas

I try to clear my canvas to draw an image on an other position:
https://jsfiddle.net/wLjo8rLn/1/

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function image(_img, _x, _y, _w, _h) {
  var img = new Image(); // Create new img element

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, _x, _y, _w, _h);
  }
  img.src = _img; // Set source path
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 32, 32);

}

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
image("http://via.placeholder.com/32x32", 0, 0, 32, 32);
```

Canvas get cleared exept all drawn image.
I am new in developing with canvas. But I habe no clue.

Comment: onload is async and thus will fire after clearRect

Comment: Thank you! But without loading this way the image is not showing: https://jsfiddle.net/ykw8nahr/

Comment: Kaiido said all you need to know, what is the problem? you cannot clearRect the image before it has loaded & drawn.

Comment: I understand the problem in my code but I can't solve it. I tried to replace onload (https://jsfiddle.net/ykw8nahr/) But in this case the image does not show up. Even if I remove clearRect().

Comment: you have to preload all images and wait for callback: https://gist.github.com/eikes/3925183